# How to specify multiple strings in an xml file to be changed in Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am helping out migrate old tech docs from my old company to the new company. I need to remove the old company references that are like this:
ABC Divisionname ProductName
to
ProductName.

And it can also be
Divisionname ProductName
to
ProductName.

There are also the old names of the tech docs to the new names:
techdoc to newdocname

I found some scripts that can do 1 at a time. I then found a glob script that do multiple files at once making 1 change.

I found some scripts that can do 1 xml file change at a time. 
I then found a glob script that do multiple files at once making 1 change.

```
import glob
import ntpath
import os

output_dir = "output"

if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
os.makedirs(output_dir)

for f in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    with open(f, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
        with open('%s/%s' % (output_dir, ntpath.basename(f)), 'w',       encoding='utf-8') as outputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            outputfile.write(line.replace('OldCompanyName ProductName', 'ProductName'))
```

My goal is to change both of old product names to the new one. Is line.replace the best way to go? 
If so, can I do "ABC Divisionname ProductName" | "Divisionname", "ProductName" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular Expression substitute method [ re.sub ]
Below is an example that may help.

```
import re

sample_xml_data = 'ABC Divisionname ProductName is the company name'

sample_xml_data_1 = 'Divisionname ProductName is the company name'

# Here is your pattern
old_company_name_pattern = re.compile('ABC Divisionname ProductName|Divisionname ProductName')

new_company_name = 'ProductName'

print(re.sub(old_company_name_pattern,new_company_name,sample_xml_data))
print(re.sub(old_company_name_pattern,new_company_name,sample_xml_data_1))
```

> output :
>
> ProductName is the company name
>
> ProductName is the company

for your example , you can use like this

```
import re
import glob
import ntpath
import os

output_dir = "output"

if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
os.makedirs(output_dir)

old_company_name_pattern = re.compile('ABC Divisionname ProductName|Divisionname ProductName')
for f in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    with open(f, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
        with open('%s/%s' % (output_dir, ntpath.basename(f)), 'w',       encoding='utf-8') as outputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            outputfile.write(re.sub(old_company_name_pattern,'ProductName',line))
```